Is this a valid solution for this basic topology exercise? (not homework)
Let $F:X\times Y \rightarrow Z$. We call $F$ continuous in each variable if for each $y_0$ in $Y$, the map $h:X\rightarrow Z$ defined by $h(x)=F(x,y_0)$ is continuous, and for each $x_0$ in $X$, the map $k:Y\rightarrow Z$ defined by $k(y) = F(x_0,y)$ is continuous. Show that if $F$ is continuous, then $F$ is continuous in each variable.
Proof:
Choose $y_0$ in $Y$. We want to show that $h:X\rightarrow Z$ defined as $h(x):=F(x,y_0)$ is continuous by showing that preimages of open sets in $Z$ are open in $X$
Let $W$ be open in $Z$. I claim that
$$F^{-1}(W)\cap (X\times\{ y_0\}) = h^{-1}(W)\times \{y_0\}$$
Since $F$ is continuous, $F^{-1}(W)$ is open in $X\times Y$ and therefore $F^{-1}(W)\cap (X\times\{ y_0\})$ is open in $X\times\{ y_0\}$, and so is $h^{-1}(W)\times \{y_0\}$. So $h^{-1}(W)$ must be open in $X$. Since $y_0$ is arbitrary, $F$ is continuous in the first variable. Now do the same proof for the other variable and it follows that $F$ is separately continuous in each variable.
I know this was asked before with different proofs, but I want to know if this in particular is a valid one. I'm not sure about the last part where it says that $h^{-1}(W)$ is open in $X$. Does it suffice to notice that the projection onto the first factor in an open map?

This proof is a bit confusing, perhaps you can edit it before someone has another look. Presumably you are trying to prove that for any open set in $Z$ its pre-images under $h$ and $k$ are open in $X$ and $Y$ respectively, but you begin by choosing an open set in $Y$, and not $Z$.

This is easier if you consider what form the product topology takes for two variables.

@Carlyle
I corrected. I meant W open in Z. F is a continuous map from XxY to Z, so the preimage of W via F is open in XxY.

@Carlyle I made it more clear. What i want to show is, as you said, that preimages via h and via k are open in X and Y respectively. I only included the proof for h since the one for k would be identical. You think it's not clear enough?
